# GitHub "remote: Permission to personalaccount/somefile.git denied to clientaccount"

Tags: git, macos, github, ssh

I have created a new GitHub account recently for a client and used my Macbook to make a new repo and publish some files. (I have never pushed anything with my personal account on my Macbook before that.) When I tried to switch back to my personal account and publish some files to my personal account, I got this:

> remote: Permission to personalaccount/somefile.git denied to clientaccount
>
> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/personalaccount/somefile.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

So I suspected that it might be a SSH problem and found some solutions. What confuses me is that when I tried to look into the client's account SSH setting on GitHub, I couldn't find any public key stored there. So I checked my personal account and found two keys: one to my macbook and one to my windows. I think they were created when I first joined Github. Then I went back to my macbook's .ssh and I couldn't find *id_rsa* or *id_rsa.pub*, instead I found *github_rsa* and *github_rsa.pub*, which contains my personal account email. I then tried to push something to my client's repo and it worked fine.

How come there's no SSH info on my client's github SSH setting, but I could push files into that repo? But I couldn't push files into my own personal account? Is *github_rsa.pub* the right file to look into?

Comment: Is is not clear what you want to hear. Your url for git is using HTTPS and you are talking about SSH authentication with public key, which is totally different thing.

Comment: I'm not sure if that has anything to do with SSH to be honest. But I have seen other solutions pointing to SSH and that's the direction that I'm inspecting. So there's another way to work around it for HTTPS connection?